# Already mentioned the link to the privacy policy and terms of use, but still apple rejected the build

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase

Apple rejected the build and gave this reason.

```
Additionally, we noticed that your Application Description did not fully meet the terms and conditions for auto-renewing subscriptions, as specified in Schedule 2, Section 3.8(b). Meeting the terms of this agreement is required by the App Store Review Guidelines. 

Specifically, your Application Description did not include:

1) the length of the subscription
2) the price of the subscription
3) information about the auto-renewable nature of the subscription
4) links to the privacy policy and terms of use
```

I already added the link to app store page in privacy policy url.
what is the reason for this.Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I got same issue.  The app has passed previously.

> We noticed that your app did not fully meet the terms and conditions for auto-renewing subscriptions, as specified in [Schedule 2](https://www.apple.com/itunes/go/itunesconnect/contracts), Section 3.8(b).

So, I added a list of text to fulfill "information about the auto-renewable nature of the subscription":

- Payment will be charged to iTunes Account at confirmation of purchase
- Subscription automatically renews unless auto-renew is turned off at least 24-hours before the end of the current period
- Account will be charged for renewal within 24-hours prior to the end of the current period, and identify the cost of the renewal
- Subscriptions may be managed by the user and auto-renewal may be turned off by going to the user's Account Settings after purchase

Comment: I got the same issue. where did you add those list of text?

Comment: I added those text in the same screen where "Buy now for $" button is.  That screen displays IAP information I setup in iTunes connect, followed by a button with "Buy now" which trigger the payment and then followed by those static texts.  My app got approval after I added those lines.

Comment: Thanks, I finally add those info on app description in itunesconnect and I got the approval. I got Dropbox as example : https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/dropbox/id327630330?mt=8

Comment: I already have a privacy policy, do I need a terms of use as well?